# Owl carousel non existant

Tags: javascript, html, owl-carousel

Ive tried a number of ways of re-aranging my code in my js files, re-aranging by scripts and a number of other things that I found on here, but unfortunately it still isnt working. I have no clue what to do anymore.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  <
head><title> Audi Home</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">


<!-- Slider
    ================================================== -->
 <link href="css/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
 <link href="css/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

<!-- Stylesheet
    ================================================== -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.min.css">
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800,600,300'    rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <script tyupe="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <!-- Loader -->


 <!-- Navigation
    ==============================-->
 <nav id="menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <img src="img/audi-logo3.jpg" class="img-responsive pull-right" style="margin-    right: 15px">
    <div clas="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <div class="nav-container">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                    <li><a href="#" class="page-scroll">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="page-scroll"> Models</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="page-scroll">Owners & Customers</a>    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="page-scroll">Shopping Tools</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="page-scroll">Global Inovation</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
     </nav>
</div>
</nav>
<section style="margin-top: 85px;">
        <div class="owl-carousel">
        <div>
            <img src="img/audi-r8.jpg">
        </div>
        <div> 
            <img src="img/audi-s8.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>



</section>





 <!-- Script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

My JS

```
(function(){

    $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            loop:true,
            margin:10,
            nav:true,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:1
            },  
                600:{
                    items:3
                },
                1000:{
                    items:5
                }
            }
        })
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `script` tags from the `head` section, as they are already at the bottom of your `body` tag.

The problem is caused by the order you used there. If you need to use a library in your own code, you must declare that library first. That was not the case in your `head` section. It should be ok with what you have at the bottom of your `body` section.

Also, I don't see any `script` tag for jQuery, but you are using it. You need to include that first:

Just before `</body>`:

```
<!-- This script is hosted on a CDN, but you could host it too -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I noticed a typo

```
<!-- Stylesheet
================================================== -->
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.min.css">
       <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
       <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,800,600,300'    rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 THIS ONE --> <script **tyupe**="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
      </head>
```

Also, I see that you are script loading the same 2 scripts at the bottom of your HTML, but the non minified versions.  You should delete what is not being used, and fix that typo.

If you would of HTML validate/check your files, you would of found that typo error.  Might be worth doing as there may be other simple errors.

Do you need to load a jQuery file?  Make sure it's loaded before your javascript files